# fullPage.js dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js

I am trying to figure out what and how to do a dropdown menu but I can't find my problem or what I am missing.

When I try to click/tap on the button it doesn't do anything (it doesn't drop anything).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the menu.

```
<ul id="menu">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I am really new at this so probably this is a simple problem but I still can't figure it out.

Also if there is a simpler solution or without bootstrap I would like to try them all.

Comment: Difficult to guess without a reproduction of the issue in jsffiddle or codepen.

Comment: Try using the fullpage.js option `verticalCentered: false`. That will prevent modifying your original DOM structure and your content inside sections won't be considered "dynamically added". Maybe that's why it is not working?

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for your time but I found a way to do that. Please check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling and trying different approaches I found a way to do what I want.

You should use `Bootstrap.css`, `Bootstrap.js`, `jQuery.js` and `Popper.js`.

Also you should set `crossorigin="anonymous"`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/popper-1.14.7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also about the using of the JavaScripts you can use it this way: (as stated [here - Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/))

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's the menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will help to some people because I found couple of questions similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have created fiddle example using bootstrap js and bootsrap css similar given your code and i have also added fullpage js but dropdown working fine.

Please check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gp5htuz1/). its working fine. JS and Css file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullPage.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul id="menu">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```